# MERN with NEXTJS the static pics from the backend won't load on deployment. The frontend is using its URL instead of backend URL how do I fix this

Tags: heroku, deployment, next.js, mern, netlify

this is from the Feature page. It works fine locally but on deployment things do not work as it does locally. The products all load but the images do not. I checked the network and the red wording said that it is requesting it from the frontend URL instead of the backend. What do I do

```
return (
    <>
      {showError(error, error)}
      <div className="featured-product">
        <div
          className="featured-image"
          onClick={() => router.push(`/product/${_id}`)}
        >
          {/* <img src={imageUrl.src} alt={alt} /> */}
          {/* <img src={`${IMAGEAPI}img/products/${product.photo}`} alt={alt} /> */}
          {/* tryin to see if this works on production */}
          <img src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}img/products/${product.photo}`} alt={alt} />
        </div>
        <div className="name-price" >
          {/* this was apart of the div name-price above */}
           {/* onChange={(e)=>SizeToPrice(e)} > */}
          <h3>
            {name} {productType}
          </h3>
          <p>${price}</p>
          <p>qty:{quantity}</p>
          <p className="averageRating">
            <FaStar /> {product.ratingAverage}
            <Link href= {`/product/${_id}#review`} id='review' name ='review'><a style ={{display: "inline"}}> ({product.ratingQuantity})</a>
            </Link>
```

this is from another file but it does render the products

```
    export const getCategories = () => {
  return axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}category`);
};
```

when I click on the network tab it request the url from the front end and the undefined for where the {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL} goes. How do I get it to go to just the backend as it works when I do it locally but for some reason not on Deployment

Answer (score 0):

Soooo I found out I had the wrong spelling of the variables on the deployment.

Morale of the story, use COPY AND PASTE. Guarantees no issues